# What is diffrence and usage of CallInst, InvokeInst and CallSite in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I am reading LLVM Programmer’s Manual but I get confused with the term **CallInst**, **InvokeInst** and **CallSite** and their usage. Can somebody explain me in detail with example its usage and its function in LLVM.

Comment: The source code is usually helpful to understanding LLVM. In this case, the first sentence of CallSite.h ought to tell you what you want.

Comment: @arnt Can you please describe with some example

Comment: Invoke can return normally or via an exception, whereas CallInst has the normal return semantics.  I do not know CallSite though.